# The css BEM concept

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get around the Block-Element-Modifier concept of the CSS and I am a bit confused. Here is a sample code

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-header">
        <h3>Block Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My understanding is that classes .block, .block-header, .block-content, and .block-footer are the BLOCKS of the BEM concept (*correct me if it is not*) but then what is `<h3> and <p>` a block or an element?

it just hit me so **editing the question**,

If both `<h3> and <p>` are Blocks (*in case if it is*) what probably can be the elements to these two tags?

**EDITed again**

Here is block of code in html

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="user-image"> <img class="user-image__image" src="image/1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="user-meta">
            <h3 class="user-meta__username user-meta__username-red"> Trump </h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav__item nav__item_active"><a class="nav__link">One</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link">Two</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please go through the above code and let me know if this is what is correct,

1. `.block, .block-content, .block-image, .user-meta and .nav`are BLOCKS of the BEM
2. `user-meta__username and nav__item` are the Elements of the BEM.
3. `user-meta__username-red` is the Modifier of the BEM.

Comment: Hi. BEM clearly states that elements should be followed by double underscores, like `block__header` instead of `block-header`. But of course, you are free to choose your own styling of the elements. The concept is explained clearly [here](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/). If you prefer a visual guide, consult this [section](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/). Best of luck!

Comment: I started a couple of days ago so new to it, yes I have read about the naming conventions, I thought that the block-header class was a block too. This is what I wrote too .. So is the block-header, block-content and block-footer Elements or Blocks?

Comment: Hey, thats a nice looking tutorial .... thank you @Helenesh.

Comment: It depends. I would research it as much as possible and look through examples. It can be difficult to grasp in the beginning, but you'll get the hang of it. All I can do is repeat what's inside the documentation. Good luck!

Comment: @Helenesh, I just went through the tutorial you posted. It says Blocks can be nested in each other and you can have any number of nesting levels, so my understanding is block-header, block-content and block-footer are blocks. Can you verify.

Comment: https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#a-block-or-an-element-which-one-should-i-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all naming and structure is a personal thing. Although BEM concept is quite clear. It's a guideline, not a law.

**Block:**
How many blocks, element or modifiers you have depends on how much you like to reuse your own code. The number of blocks (repeating elements) can be as big or small as what you desire in your own project. My own guidelines are that I only use a block when I know the situation will be repeated.

**CSS guidelines for blocks:**

1. Use class name selector only
2. No tag name or ids No dependency on
3. other blocks/elements on a page

**Element:**
The element part of BEM is the block it's "static" content. This can be non-repeated elements like single use heading styles, list styles, graphical elements etc. You never mix an other blocks elements inside it's own block.
Example:

**GOOD:**

`<div class="logo">
  <img src="/" class="logo__image">
</div>`

**BAD:**

`<div class="logo">
  <img src="/" class="branding__logo">
</div>`

**CSS guidelines for elements**

1. Use class name selector only
2. No tag name or ids
3. No dependency on other blocks/elements on a page

**Modifier:**
Modifiers can be used on blocks and elements depending on how much you want to change the layout when an action happens. This can be highlighting something to completely change the designs look. Or just hide stuff.

**CSS guidelines for modifiers**

1. To alter elements based on a block-level modifier
2. To alter elements based on a element modifier

More about BEM can be found here: http://getbem.com/

**Example of your code:**

```html
<!-- Begin block: topbar -->
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="topbar__content">
    
    <!-- Begin block: user -->
    <div class="user">
      <img class="user__image" src="image/1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="user__meta">
        <h3 class="user__username user__username--red"> Trump </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Begin block: nav -->
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav__item nav__item--active"><a class="nav__link">One</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link">Two</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be aware that this is my personal take away from the BEM concept. Be free to disagree or use other methodes.

Answer (score 1):

BEM Follows a naming convention of `block__element--modifier`
Giving an example

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item menu__item--active"></li>
  <li class="menu__item"></li>
  <li class="menu__item"></li>
  <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>
```

Block - `menu`,
Element - `menu__item`,
Modifier - `menu__item--active`

Comment: You still did not answer my question, are .block, .block-header, .block-content, and .block-footer, Blocks or Elements, what about h3 and p? I am not looking for naming conventions.

Comment: As far I read and understand that a block can be nested into another block, so all three classes are Blocks but the answer above confuses me even further.

Comment: First thing we don't need to mention 'block' when the header/content/footer itself is a block element. when it comes to h3 and p most of the time these tags would be used as elements(maybe 'title' or 'description'). 
Giving another example - 
content, 
content__title, 
content__description

Comment: I name a div of my page block, so that makes it a block, I could have used box but block sounds better, second that Block is further divided into three section header,  content and a footer, I know I am doing right till here so yeah you can name that a BLOCK. And after going through https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#block I feel yes those sections are definitely blocks of the BEM concept. h3 and p are elements and I think they are in this case too.

Comment: how about this, a header, a footer or content can further have collection of blocks. A nav is a block, which has further a logo block, a menu block and search-bar block ... Yes, yes, yes, yups I got the block portion, now to the element.